# Magento 1.14.2.2 Roll over image on PLP

Tags: php, magento

Hey I have recently added a line of code that enables the thumbnail image to be shown when the image is rolled over in the Product Listing Page.

`onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize($_imgSize) ?>';" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize($_imgSize) ?>';"/>`

This line was added in the /template/catalog/product/list.phtml file so it now the image code is as follows:

```
 <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(283, null)->keepFrame(false); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" 
        onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize($_imgSize) ?>';" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize($_imgSize) ?>';"/>
        </a>
```

When checking my system.log file, I am getting the following error message:

Notice: Undefined variable: _imgSize  in /var/www/deploy/releases/20180227152715/app/design/frontend/my theme/my theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 56

I know that the _imgSize variable must be defined here

```
<?php
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
 $_imgSize = null;//not defining rollover image deminsions
?>
```

I just do not know what the _imgSize would be defined as. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters you give to this function are **the sizes in pixels**.
Here is its definition :

```php
/**
 * Schedule resize of the image
 * $width *or* $height can be null - in this case, lacking dimension will be calculated.
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image
 * @param int $width
 * @param int $height
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image
 */
public function resize($width, $height = null)
{
    $this->_getModel()->setWidth($width)->setHeight($height);
    $this->_scheduleResize = true;
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I actually used what you told me and realized that all I needed to do was state "$_imgSize = null;" because I did not need to have the image resized. Everything still works and I am no longer receiving the error in the system log files.

Comment: @L.Blanchard indeed ! If you do not need to resize the image, you're not even forced to call the function resize() ; it's even a better thing not to do it, as it will force the system to generate cache images for all these files, which is very heavy regarding the resources of the server. The image helper is special, as it defines the __toString() function ; in short, after you called the init() function, you can directly use the echo() function of php on this helper to output the image.

Comment: @L.Blanchard just delete this chunk : 
->resize($_imgSize)